# Get unique array from array of object in javascript based on two property

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object

I need get a unique value from an object of array. Forexample i have a following data,

```
   var empDetails =[
{"name":"dinesh","age":"24","companyName":"ABC","designation":"developer"},
{"name":"dinesh","age":"24","companyName":"ABC","designation":"developer"},{"name":"dinesh","age":"24","companyName":"ABC","designation":"TestEngr"},
{"name":"Ramesh","age":"24","companyName":"ABC","designation":"developer"}];
```

from this object i want to get the unique array details.
output should be like following:

```
uniqueDet = [
{"name":"dinesh","age":"24","companyName":"ABC","designation":"developer"},
 {"name":"dinesh","age":"24","companyName":"ABC","designation":"TestEngr"},
    {"name":"Ramesh","age":"24","companyName":"ABC","designation":"developer"}]
```

Based on companyname and designation i want to get the unique details. 
Can you kindly give me solution to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use a deduplication implementation that uses an explicit comparison of elements, and then use your custom comparison (by two properties) there.

Comment: i dont want to use any libraries... i wanted to implement by using javascript only.. I tried to implement it by iteration .. Is there any other gud way to do ...

Comment: I did not say you needed to use a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var uniqueDet = empDetails.filter(function(x, i) {
    return empDetails.map(function(e) { 
        return JSON.stringify(e)
     }).indexOf(JSON.stringify(x)) == i;
});
```

Comment: How does this filter for `companyName` and `designation`?

Comment: @Bergi by comparing strings,  `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` compares the whole object, not only those two properties

Comment: @Bergi if we don't compare `name` we would have to remove this `{ "name": "Ramesh", "age": "24", "companyName": "ABC", "designation": "developer" },`, but it's wrong